# Label the exponential value of a data point on a secondary y axis in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-analysis

I am trying to recreate something similar to the following graph

[Time-frequency graph with two y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXIg9.png)

There are two y-axis, the left one shows frequency to the  -8/3 power, the right one labels the original frequency with uneven distribution.

While I can make a secondary y axis, I am not sure how to use it to only label the value of a data point like they did in the picture.

Edit:[Clumped y label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrgR2.png)

Edit 2: For some reason the secondary y axis isn't correctly using scientific notation, after multiplying the ticks by 10^5, everything looked normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Example data
time = np.array([0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.40, 0.41, 0.42])
frequency = np.array([5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1])  # Example frequency data

# Create figure and axis
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# Plot the main data on ax1
ax1.plot(time, frequency ** (-8/3), 'g-')  # Plot frequency to the -8/3 power

# Set the y-axis label
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency (f)^{-8/3}', color='g')

# Create a secondary y-axis that shares the same x-axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Function to calculate the original frequency from the transformed frequency
def original_freq(transformed_freq):
    return transformed_freq ** (-3/8)

# Get the transformed frequency values and calculate the corresponding original frequency
transformed_freq = frequency ** (-8/3)
original_freq_values = original_freq(transformed_freq)

# Set the secondary y-axis ticks and labels
ax2.set_yticks(transformed_freq)
ax2.set_yticklabels([f'{f:.0f} Hz' for f in original_freq_values], color='b')

# Set the secondary y-axis label
ax2.set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', color='b')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi there, while your code works, when I retry to use my own data, the labels on the right y-axis are all clumped into a tight corner, any idea why? I made an edit and added my image

Comment: Figured it out, for someone the secondary y axes isn't correctly using scientific notation like the first y axes, after multiply the ticks by 10^5, it looked normal